# android app stucks in waiting for debugger

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-debugging, android-studio-flamingo

Since I've installed a newer version of android studio i.e. `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1` my application always waits for a debugger when executing debugging from android studio.

I have tried a lower version of the Android Studio on the same PC and emulator and it works flawlessly (using the same version of adb.exe and etc.) So I cannot imagine what I've missed in the new version of android studio to make it work with an emulator while debugging.

I should mention that I've browsed different solutions covered in the Stackoverflow but nothing worked such as invalidate cache + enable/disable develoer options.

I'm suspect to gradle + Android studio combination.

The android studio stops adb session and prompts: 'process xxx.yyy.zzz not found. aborting session'.

I also added `android:debuggable="true"` in my manifest to allow debugger attach my application but it does not help.

I should add that my app have build flavors and I don't know does it might affect the debugger?

I have no firewall enabled on my PC and no process listens to port 8600.

Version of my tools:

**ADB**
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874

**Android Studio** Flamingo | 2022.2.1

**Gradle**: 7.5.1

Comment: Do you have multiple devices connected via adb? Try to restart adb: `adb kill-server` (or simply kill all adb instances) `adb start-server`.

Comment: I have tried this as well. But it did not help. I have disabled other emulator instances so `adb devices` list only one device.

Comment: Try creating a reproducible that you can share, otherwise I don't think someone can help you.

Comment: I just added version of my android studio tools, since I'm suspect to android studio itself.

Comment: What is you JAVA_HOME path ?

Answer (score 1):

`adb` server may need to be killed first so that next time you run the debugger it can attach to the process correctly. Run this (on macOS):

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
```

and then try to run the debugger again

Comment: It didn't help. I've tried this several times.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 and reinstalling an earlier version that you know works well with your setup.

Comment: Earlier versions are not compatible with newer version of gradle and SDKs.

Comment: Let me find the better solution.
Thank you for considering my idea.